# generate random number between 10 to 1000000000 in C

Tags: c, random

I am using this code to create; but all the results are in range of `10` to `32000`.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    *(A + i) = rand() % (1000000000 - 10 + 1) + 10;
    printf("%lu\n", *(A + i));
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `i`?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not reading the `rand` documentation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

Comment: Hi Eli; i is int.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` returns a value in the range of 0 and `RAND_MAX` (which, according to the standard, is at least 32767): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

If you want a higher value you can multiply multiple rand() results.

Comment: Better to shift and OR for a larger range than `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` might be as small as 32767; it might be larger, depending on your system. The standard only specifies the minimum.

Comment: @rici thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: Multiplying multiple `rand()` results to obtain a larger value is a very idea. The resulting distribution of values will be heavily skewed towards smaller values, and will exclude many numbers (including all the prime numbers higher than RAND_MAX). As @WeatherVane suggests, you should instead use shift and OR operations instead.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that was a conceptual direction. The idea is to combine multiple `RAND()` calls. It doesn't have to be skewed (e.g. `RAND() * (RAND() + 10000)`, and anyway sometimes it's better to point a beginner at the direction of a simple solution. That said, shifting would be good and it's good that it was posted here as well.

Answer (score 1):

1,000,000,000 (3B9ACA00) is a 30-bit number.

`rand()` generates results in the `[0...RAND_MAX]` range.  `RAND_MAX` may be as small as 32,767, a 15-bit number// `RAND_MAX` may be as large as `INT_MAX`.  Multiple calls to `rand()` are needed when `RAND_MAX < (1000000000 - 10 + 1)`, the number of different values sought by OP.

The below throws out small or larges values (about 7% of the time) and tries again.  This is done to maintain a fair distribution of numbers.

```
uint32_t rand_10_to_1000000000(void) {
  // This method only works well when RAND_MAX is 2**n -1.
  // This is commonly true
  assert((RAND_MAX + (uint32_t) 1) & RAND_MAX == 0);

  uint32_t r;
  do {
    r = rand();
    #if RAND_MAX < 0x3FFFFFFF
      // Adding 1 to RAND_MAX as an int should be avoided to prevent int overflow.
      r *= RAND_MAX + (uint32_t) 1;
      r += rand();
    #endif
    r &= 0x3FFFFFFF; // only use lower 30 bits.
  } while (r < 10 || r > 1000000000);
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what documentation says about rand() return value:

```
 An integer value between 0 and RAND_MAX.
```

And here is what documentation says about RAND_MAX:

```
 This value is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767 on any standard library implementation.
```

So in your implementation RAND_MAX can probably generate numbers up to 32767. You probably have to generate upper and lower bits independently like:

```
int big_rand()
{
    return rand() | (rand() << 15);
}
```

Comment: You should mask out the upper bits just to be sure and get better results.

Comment: When combining random bits, better to `^` than `|`.  This is important, in general, as  `rand() | (rand() << 15)` relies on `RAND_MAX == 32767` and C specifies that only as a _minimum_.

Answer (score 0):

Your system's implementation of `rand()` has limited precision.  The standard mandates that `RAND_MAX` be at least `32767`.  You system seems to use this minimum value.

You can combine multiple random values to compute your samples:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {                
    A[i] = 10 + (rand() | ((unsigned)rand() << 15)) % (1000000000 - 10 + 1);
    printf("%lu\n", A[i]);
}
```

PS: why do you write `*(A+i)` instead of the more readable `A[i]`?